# Cloud 9 browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a new user of Javascript and I'm trying to use `"require()"` in a cloud 9 project of mine. But whenever I try I get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

I was told I could use `browserify`, but I have had no luck installing it. 
I used this command to install it:

```
npm install -g browserify
```

and the first error while installing it was:

> Error: No compatible version found: browser-pack@'^6.0.1'

How can I install `browserify`, or how can I get `require` to work?
Let me know if you need more information, thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What version of npm are you using? Try updating your npm.

Comment: Thanks. It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this error when I was using an older version of NPM. Try updating your npm and it should work.